# call method from existing external .dll. For ex, CopyFileA from kernel32.dll

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, native

The task is to call method from an existing dll.
I'm trying to do that on an example of CopyFileA from kernel32.dll.

The method signature is:

```
Function long CopyFileA(String lpExistingFileName, String lpNewFileName, boolean bFailifExists) Library "kernel32"
```

This is how I'm trying to do this in java:

```
public class Test {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("D:\\test\\kernel32");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Test()).CopyFileA("D:\\test\\hi.txt", "D:\\other\\hi.txt", false);
    }

    public native long CopyFileA(String lpExistingFileName, String lpNewFileName, boolean bFailifExists);
}
```

I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Test.CopyFileA(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)J
```

All manuals that I've found describes examples when you write C code and then create dll for yourself. So, you implement native method with signature from generated header file.
But here we already have a dll.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The examples you have seen are the best way to go. There is some harness code that needs to be done to enable Java to call into a native method and visa-versa. With out this harness code there is no way for either of them to communicate with each other.

If you are desperate to call CopyFileA then create the harness code in some C/C++ code that then calls CopyFileA.

If you are trying to avoid programming in C/C++ then there is no way for your java to communicate with CopyFileA.

There may be a third party code that may help you. I don't know of any.

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple: everything you need is download [jna.jar](http://java.net/projects/jna/downloads) file and include it into your project.
Bellow I put some code snippet how to solve your task:

```
Function showWindow = Function.getFunction("kernel32", "CopyFileA");
Object[] params = new Object[3];
params[0] = "D:\\test\\hi.txt";
params[1] = "D:\\other\\hi.txt";
params[2] = false;
Object result = showWindow.invoke(params);
```